# Where is my Firefox Profile on Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-9.10, roaming-profiles

I'm dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala and want to bring over my Firefox profile, I know where it is in Windows, where is it in Ubuntu? I feel like I've looked everywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`ls ~/.mozilla/firefox/????????.default`

Comment: and replace ???? with the appropriate characters

Comment: No. Shell will do substitution automagically. Just try it!

Comment: ctrl+h will show hidden files in nautilus (the file browser). look for  the .mozilla folder inside you home folder (called ~ in the terminal).

Comment: also you can just type .mozilla in nautilus' address bar

Answer (score 1):

/home/yourusername/.mozilla/firefox/bunchoffunkycodes.default has some things like where you'd have your userstylesheet override and your bookmark backups in JSON format.  remember you won't see hidden ".files" unless you have "show hidden files" in your edit>preferences (if you're using the GUI to navigate) or the -a option if your using "ls" in the command line.

/etc/firefox(versionnumber)/profile/ should have your bookmarks in HTML format, prefs.js, and a folder called "chrome" where your user stylesheet overrides are (but if you have a user stylesheet you should place it in the first path I mentioned, in your home directory).

There's also /usr/lib/firefox(versionnumber)/defaults which should have a simlink to the profile folder mentioned above, and some other stuff.